# How to fetch Dynamic keys from JavaScript Associative array?

Tags: javascript, json, associative-array

I have a JSON string which I then convert into JSON Object by using jQuery. The string in question given below:

```
  var json = [
      {
        "1240": [
          "Order1",
          "user1"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Here key 1240 is Dynamic and I can't do something like `json[0]["1240"]` When I do something like:

```
for(var f in json )
      {
          alert(f);
      }
```

Then it returns "0"

How do I fetch **1240** here?

Comment: Of course it's 0 since it's `json[0]`. If you want to reach "1024", you need `for(var i in json[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an array of objects.

http://jsbin.com/umaWoge/1/

Try this

```
    var json = [
      {
        "1240": [
          "Order1",
          "user1"
        ]
      }
];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{
  for(var f in json[i])
      {
          alert(f);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this also.

var json = [
      {
        "1240": [
          "Order1",
          "user1"
        ]
      }
];

for (var i in json)
{
  for(var f in json[i])
      {
          alert(f);
      }
}
```